# Unable to install JDK 8 in windows

Tags: java, installation, jdk1.8-73

I have downloaded **jdk-8u101-windows-i586.exe**. My PC configuration is **Windows 7 (32 Bit)**. I have already JDK and JRE 1.7. I want to install JDK 8 as well. But when I run the installer it is showing

> the program might not have installed correctly

With two possible action as follows

> Reinstall using recommended settings.
>
> This program installed correctly.

I tried the first option but nothing happened. Even no other windows popup with error message. I tried troubleshot with help message but nothing worked.

What could be my problem. Please help me to install the JDK 8.[image]

Comment: Not a programming question. Install netbeans + java, always works smoothly.

Comment: Try reinstall as Administrator

Comment: I would recommend you get off 32-bit ASAP, my 8 year old has a machine with 24 GB, and she isn't developing code yet. You can get 64-bit phones these days.

Answer (score 1):

It might have installed correct ..set the path variable to jav installed bin path  & java_home  to java directory installed

and try running the command

java -version

Comment: Already Java is instaled with version 7. So I am expecting Java 8 folder under Program files.

Answer (score 0):

As a first step, reboot the system and try installing JDK 8u101 (32-bit) again. Sometimes, a failed install/uninstall attempt could lead to this state with stale registries. Also, make sure that you have downloaded this from the correct web site:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

If this still does not work, suggest you to submit a bug at:
http://bugs.java.com/